# ListView Asp.Net control - Assigning strings to Listview columns

Tags: asp.net, listview, asp.net-3.5

ListView Web Control question:

I developed a report service web application using Asp.Net 3.5 and ReportingService2010.asmx. I retrieved the ItemHistorySnapshots with the following code:

```
ItemHistorySnapshot[] itemSnapshots = null;
itemSnapshots = rs.ListItemHistory(strChildNode);

foreach(ItemHistorySnapshot snapshot in itemSnapshots) {
    listview.add (snapshot.HistoryID.Tostring());
    listview.add (snapshot.Size.Tostring());
    listview.add(snapshot.DateTime.Tostring());
}
```

I want to create a ListView with 3 columns HistoryID, Size, DateTime and want to assign the string values in foreach loop.

Please let me know how to assign the string values to ListView. I want to know the source control code for listview also. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an repeater and bind the data to it, like this:

Code behind:

```
ItemHistorySnapshot[] itemSnapshots = null;
itemSnapshots = rs.ListItemHistory(strChildNode);

rpt.DataSource = itemSnapshots.Select(s => new 
{
  HistoryID = s.HistoryID.ToString(),
  Size = s.Size.ToString(),
  DateTime = s.DateTime.ToString(),
});
rpt.DataBind();
```

Aspx Page:

```
<asp:Repeater id="rpt" runat="server">

  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table border="1" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <th>HistoryID</th>
          <th>Size</th>
          <th>DateTime</th>
      </tr>
  </HeaderTemplate>

  <ItemTemplate>
    <tr>
      <td><%# Eval("HistoryID") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("Size") %></td>
      <td><%# Eval("DateTime") %></td>
    </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>

  <FooterTemplate>
    </table>
  </FooterTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```